# Visibility widget not displayed in Flutter

Tags: flutter

If we have a `Visibility` widget on top of our screen and we click to display it at the end of our screen scrolling top manually, why still this hidden? Does this mean that we need to do something like this instead?:

```
showWidget == true ? Text("hi") : Container();
```

Because code above is failing as well.

Video of the error:
https://youtu.be/YQ7nZ3LAENo

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the issue? You should never return null instead of a widget. Try returning SizedBox instead of null

Comment: refresh. It doesn't matter what I return

Comment: I thought the problem was related to `table_calendar` first but it is not. Return a simple container and trying `Visibility` or just a normal check gives same result

Comment: Are you calling setState() when you change `_optionSelected`?

Comment: it's `_showCalendar `, but yes

Comment: the calendar button I click is basically a setState updating `_showCalendar` value, nothing else

Comment: Oh okay, all the visible options that I see in the video are based on `_optionSelected`. Have you tried adding a `replacement` widget to `Visibility`? Does it changes?

Comment: that's what I got before and it was giving me same result. No difference between `Visibility` and a normal variable check

Comment: also tried on my real device and same result, so it's not an emulator error

Comment: This [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/b37899c36db6c2007fd27954ce4d78ed) is working correctly. Does it has any difference with your implementation?

Comment: that example doesn't have any scroll

Comment: How about now? [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/b37899c36db6c2007fd27954ce4d78ed)

Comment: I don't see any problem there... not sure how different that dartPard is. I'll do some workaround and I'll double check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207994/discussion-between-sebastian-and-dani).